# iconv: Converting from Windows ANSI to UTF-8 with BOM

Tags: unicode, iconv

I want to use `iconv` to convert files on my Mac. The goal is to go from "Windows ANSI" to "whatever Windows Notepad saves, if you tell it to use UFT8".

This is what I want:

```
$ file names.csv 
names.csv: UTF-8 Unicode (with BOM) text, with CRLF line terminators
```

This is what I use:

```
$ iconv -f CP1252 -t UTF-8  names.csv > names.utf8.csv
```

This is what I get (not what I want):

```
$ file names.utf8.csv 
names.utf8.csv: UTF-8 Unicode text, with CRLF line terminators
```

How do I get the BOM?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can add it manually by first `echo`ing the bytes into the file:

```
echo -ne '\xEF\xBB\xBF' > names.utf8.csv
```

and then concatenating your required information at the end:

```
iconv -f CP1252 -t UTF-8  names.csv >> names.utf8.csv
```

Note the `>>` rather than `>`.

Comment: Any idea why iconv from GnuWin is creating a UCS2 LE BOM encoded file (according to Notepad++ anyway) when I use `-t UTF-8` ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3604753/iconv-is-converting-to-utf-16-instead-of-utf-8-when-invoked-from-powershell

Comment: Nice solution. It also works with UTF-32LE `echo -ne '\xFF\xFE\x00\x00' >  names.utf8.csv`.

Answer (score 1):

Note that "Windows ANSI" may not be CP1252 - that is configured by users.

Answer (score -3):

The BOM is not necessary for UTF-8.
And Windows Notepad can save UTF-8 with or without BOM.

Answer (score -7):

I needed the opossite. (covert german text from UTF-8 to ANSI)

So command I used:
1.  iconv -l (check available formats)
2.  iconv -f UTF8 -t MS-ANSI de.txt > output.txt

and now if I open output.txt it is already in ANSI. Job done.

Comment: The question asked specifically about the BOM, so I don't think your answer is helpful.