# `iconv` convert and no error BUT `file -i` show it's still *us-ascii* NOT *utf-8*

Tags: ubuntu, encoding, command-line, iconv

See, it keep to be *us-ascii*. `iconv` success with no warning, but `file -bi` show it's not converted:

```
$ file -bi tmpaaa 
    text/html; charset=us-ascii
$ iconv -f us-ascii -t utf-8 tmpaaa -o tmpb
$ cp tmpb tmpaaa
$ file -bi tmpaaa 
    text/html; charset=us-ascii
$
```

And my another scripts keep complain it's not *utf-8*.  Who know what's happened? The
machine is *Ubuntu/Linux*, LANG=en_US-UTF-8

Answer (score 4):

Maybe your file doesn't contain any special character (only English letters, numbers and punctuation)?

Comment: +1 It should be pointed out that a file containing only ASCII characters is simply already in UTF-8 format, too. If it's correctly encoded in US-ASCII then there is no "maybe".

Comment: Correct, but the other script might expect a BOM, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4365180/33499)