# Opening Word doc title encoded in ansi in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer, xslt, encoding, utf-8, internet-explorer-8

In IE 8 when I download a document which I've coded in C#/xslt/xml the title of the document should be '£sqft' but it's 'Â£sqft'.

I kind of guess the reason - its because the string is encoded in .NET in utf-16 and IE 8 uses ansi to read it. I'm guessing this because using notepad++ if I enter £ in utf-8 then switch to ANSI it preceeds the character with this other character.

How do I get IE 8 to read it as utf-8?

Here is the code for creating the document where I'm passing an xsl file the name of which is '£sqft' which exports as 'Â£sqft':

```
        TextWriter output;       
        DataSet ds = 'some dataset'
        XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument(); 
        xDoc.LoadXml(ds.GetXml());
        xt.Load("c:/£sqft.xsl");    
        xt.Tran
```

sform(xDoc, null, output);

Comment: What are you setting the content-type to in the header when you send it to the browser?

Comment: I was thinking about that...It's Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename="+ sXslFile)

Comment: Oh, you're actually saving it as a file? Do you have a `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` declaration at the top of the file? You shouldn't need one (UTF-8 should be assumed as a default), but it might be worth trying.

Comment: Hi, yes its at the top of the file...however its the title of the file that messes up not the contents of the file.

Comment: The response header is: Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename="+ "£sqft.doc" I've tried Response.Write('\uFEFF'); Response.BinaryWrite(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetPreamble());

Comment: possible duplicate of [iconv: Converting from Windows ANSI to UTF-8 with BOM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4364156/iconv-converting-from-windows-ansi-to-utf-8-with-bom)