# Reading large excel file with special characters in pandas

Tags: windows, excel, encoding, utf-8, pandas

I have a file 500MB+ that has been generated by saving a large excel spreadsheet as unicode.
I am running windows 7.

I need to open the file with python pandas. So far I used to convert the file from ANSI to UTF-8 with notepad++ but the file is now too large and then open it with notepad++.

I have Hebrew, French, Swedish, Norwegian, Danish special characters.

- Panda's `read_excel` is just too slow * I let it go for several minutes without seeing some output.
- [`iconv`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4364156/iconv-converting-from-windows-ansi-to-utf-8-with-bom): apparently I can not get the encoding right, I just get out a list of tab separated nulls when I have [tried](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221176/excel-to-csv-with-utf8-encoding):

  iconv -f "CP858" -t "UTF-8" file1.txt > file2.txt

  iconv -f "windows-1252" -t "UTF-8" file1.txt > file2.txt

**Edit**

`iconv -f "UTF-16le" -t "UTF-8" file1.txt > file2.txt` leads to a very weird behaviour: a row in between lines is cut. All looks fine but only 80K rows are actually converted.

**Edit 2**

.. `read_csv` with `encoding='utf-16le'` reads properly the file. However, I still don't get why `iconv` messes it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`read_csv` with `encoding='utf-16le'` reads properly the file. However, I still don't get why `iconv` messes it up.