# Convert file to UTF-8 without BOM using iconv on windows 8

Tags: encoding, iconv

I need to convert a bunch of files to:

```
UTF-8 without BOM
```

[image]

I have installed iconv:
http://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/

But I can only find the *plain* UTF-8 option:

```
iconv --list
ANSI_X3.4-1968 ANSI_X3.4-1986 ASCII CP367 IBM367 ISO-IR-6 ISO646-US ISO_646.IRV:1991 US US-ASCII CSASCII
UTF-8
ISO-10646-UCS-2 UCS-2 CSUNICODE
```

So after I run the conversion the file is now in:

[image]

Is it not possible to convert to:
    UTF-8 without BOM

using iconv?

Comment: You are wrong in assuming `iconv` adds the BOM. See the reverse: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4364156/iconv-converting-from-windows-ansi-to-utf-8-with-bom. A test on my system (OSX) and then inspecting the result with a hex editor confirms this.