# Extension's context menu on Safari does not show quote and emoji

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, safari, contextmenu, safari-extension

I have this code:

[image]

It shows correctly on Google Chrome:

[image]

It just shows odd characters on Safari:

[image]

What could be the possible reason why the quote and emoji are not shown correctly?

Comment: The only reason is a bug/limit in Safari.

Comment: @wOxxOm I noticed that the emojis and other characters are displayed correctly by Safari when displayed directly from a website. Apparently, Xcode build and bundle the browser extension files incorrectly depending on the encoding of file, hence the string gets mangled when compiled/bundled to the final app. I noticed the root cause of the problem when I look at the background.js in Safari > Develop > Web Extension Background Pages > *Extension Name Here*

Comment: See my answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70014651/extensions-context-menu-on-safari-does-not-show-quote-and-emoji/70224351#70224351

Answer (score 0):

It's working now

[image]

For some reasons, the extension builder of Xcode bundled the javascript strings wrongly

A solution is to convert the background.js to UTF-16. It involve three steps:

1. Open the background.js in VS Code, and then click the **UTF-8** button in the status bar:

[image]

2. Select **Save with encoding**

[image]

3. Select **UTF-16 LE**

[image]

Final step, build the Xcode Safari Extension project. You can now use accented characters and emojis to your heart's content

If anyone have a good idea why Xcode cannot build Safari extension straight out of a UTF-8 file, please offer some theory why it is so. Or if there are any other alternative solution to this problem

A bit shorter steps (two steps), use iconv commandline utility to convert the UTF-8 file background.js to UTF-16LE, but it's not enough, the emojis and other characters still looks gibberish when Xcode build the project. Still need another step, that is, open the background.js in VS Code and then save it (Ctrl+S or command+S). Looks like VS Code is doing some corrections to a file when a file is set to different encoding. Final step, build the Xcode Safari Extension project

Answer (score 0):

Setting the background.js to UTF-8 with [BOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4364156/iconv-converting-from-windows-ansi-to-utf-8-with-bom/4365180#4365180) also works

Here's an example script of converting a file to UTF-8 with BOM:

```
(rm -f background.js && cd background-src && parcel build background.mjs && mv ./dist/background.js ../x.js && rm -rf ./dist/ && rm -rf ./.parcel-cache/ && rm -rf ./.cache/ && echo -ne '\xEF\xBB\xBF' > ../background.js && cat ../x.js >> ../background.js && rm ../x.js)
```