# powershell converting utf-8 to latin1 with iconv.exe

Tags: powershell, utf-8, iso-8859-1, iconv

I am trying to convert a file with iconv.exe with powershell, I am getting an output file named `a.a` but it is still encoded with `utf-8` and not `latin1`.

```
$params = @{
    FilePath = "tools/iconv.exe"; 
    ArgumentList = @(
        "--from-code=utf-8",
        "--to-code=latin1",
        "$rc_file"
    );
    RedirectStandardOutput = "a.a";
    Wait = $true;
    NoNewWindow = $true
}

Start-Process @params
```

With cmd the script looked like this and it worked fine.

```
%ICONV% --from-code=utf-8 utf-8 --to-code=latin1 latin1 %1 > a.a
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Why do you want to use iconv and not just PowerShell?

Comment: --from-code=utf-8 utf-8 --to-code=latin1 latin1: that's my bad it is like this: --from-code=utf-8 --to-code=latin1 
@Clijsters can powershell convert encodings from files ?

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3604753/iconv-is-converting-to-utf-16-instead-of-utf-8-when-invoked-from-powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3604753/iconv-is-converting-to-utf-16-instead-of-utf-8-when-invoked-from-powershell)